# Does Ext.Ajax convert cross domain url to something else automatically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

The IP of my host is 10.0.0.1. I was expecting the following code would throw an exception because of the cross domain issue:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : "http://example.com",
            method: 'GET',
...
```

But when I monitored the request from fiddler,the request was actually converted to

```
http://10.0.0.1/proxy?url=http://example.com
```

That means if you setup a proxy from your server side,the request will be automatically forwarded to the destination. So who did this magic?

Answer (score 1):

For cross-domain requests try using:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url:"http://example.com"
});
```